# The fastest way to structure data in JSON for python

Tags: python, json

I have a complex document that I am trying to structure most conveniently and efficiently with JSON in Python.  I would like to be able to retrieve one of the items in my document with one line (i.e. not via a `for` loop)

A demo of the structure looks like this:

```
{
    "movies": {
        "0": {
            "name": "charles",
            "id": 0, 
            "loopable": true
        },
        "1": {
            "name": "ray",
            "id": 1, 
            "loopable": true
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to be able to easily fetch a movie based on its `id` field.  To do this, right now, I have made the `index` the same as the key to the movies object.   So when I `json.load` the object to find movie `1`'s name I can just do `movie[(id)]['name']`

It seems like I should have a `list` of movies in the json file but it also seems like that would be more complicated. It could look like this:

```
{
    "movies": [
        {
            "name": "charles",
            "id": 0, 
            "loopable": true
        },
        {
            "name": "ray",
            "id": 1, 
            "loopable": true
        }
    ]
}
```

but if that were the case I would have to loop through the entire array like this:

```
for movie in movies:
    if movie['id'] == (id)
        # Now I can get movie['id']['name']
```

Is there a more effiecient way of doing this?

Comment: If you don't want to have the movie ID be the key, you might be better off using a database like pythons built-in SQLite support.

Comment: So is the issue that you don't know how to cast the value of `id` from an integer to a string? I don't see why you can't use your original structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `'movies'` be a dict and not a list:

```
{
    "movies": {
        "12": {
            "name": "charles",
            "id": 12, 
            "loopable": true
        },
        "39": {
            "name": "ray",
            "id": 39, 
            "loopable": true
        }
    }
}
```

and you can access movie by id with `yourjson['movies'][str(id)]`

Comment: I would like to do that (as you can see in my example) but numerical strings are not valid json